# Suspension Dodge Charger

Tags: suspension, dodge, charger

I have a 2006 Dodge Charger 3.5L and I’ve been having some suspension noises and signs happen that I am completely unsure of. My front passenger sway bar link, snapped and was replaced. Didn’t have the money to do the driver one at the time, so that’s getting done this weekend. I also had both front outer tie rods replaced because my passenger one was about to break. There was too much play. But now since the tie rod replacement, my car pulls an extreme amount to the left which I’m sure is over my alignment. It also when making sharp turns either direction, u can feel a grab in the steering wheel at roughly 3/4 of a full turn. I’m still experiencing rattling when hitting potholes, and my car also is grabbed and pulled when hit potholes, or cracks in the road. Someone point me in the right direction plz

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest that you likely have a number of worn or damaged components in your front suspension and a piecemeal approach to fixing them is not going to be effective.

You need to (or have someone else do it) inspect ALL the components, bushings, ball joints, and bearings for wear and damage and replace ALL of them that need it.

Then you will be in a position to have the front-end aligned.

Note that your steering "catch" may be due to issues in the steering gear or in the suspension itself, so you will want to have both checked and determine why this is happening.